# prepend and append string to input value

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm trying to prepend and append to an input value some string, like this.

```
<input type="text" name="protezione"  value="" onSubmit="http://www.amministrazioni-zucchetti.it/protezione/CM_<?php echo (this.value) ?>.php">
```

if I put for example mountains into the input field, the final value send to a form should be:

```
http://www.amministrazioni-zucchetti.it/protezione/CM_mountains.php
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` looks like a Javascript declaration. In PHP, all variables start with `$`. The next problem is that `$this` is only used inside a PHP class. Something tells me you aren't doing this inside a class. And then, you refer to object properties using `$this->value`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="protezione" onclick="alert('http://yoururl.com/' + this.value);">
```

And in your case:

```
<input type="text" name="protezione"  onSubmit="http://www.amministrazioni-zucchetti.it/protezione/CM_' + this.value + '.php">
```

[image]

You're tried something with `<?php`, but this is the start tag for server-sided php syntax, which can't be executed or interpreted from the client - only from the server. So in this case php doesn't help. You might want to use PHP in your `.php` file you're sending the request to progrocess the data.